# How do you type "`" or "~" when grave key is used to switch between keyboard languages?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, symbols

In window you can use grave key to switch between keyboard languages. How do you type grave and Tilda symbols after that?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Apart from @m4573r answer, you can type ` and ~ by just push and hold the key for longer than 1 second.

it will appear like this

````````````````
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```````````````
````````````````

now you got the these characters :0

Answer (score 3):

You can always do it with its Alt code: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+96 for the grave accent, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+126 for the tilda.

If you want to use those accents in combination of other letters, you have mainly 3 solutions:

- Use another key combination to change your layout/input language,
- Learn by heart all alt codes for those accentuated letters,
- Use a Autohotkey script to remap your keys to avoid the ` one.

Comment: Thanks, Microsoft may provide an easy alternative method to insert these characters when it use that button for switching keyboard layout. I am looking for such method

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that some editors may have an insert symbol option, allowing to click the characters from list and copy it to clipboard.